# Accessing static field in Java class from jruby

Tags: java, static, jruby

In java class Bytes I have:

```
public final static Comparator<byte []> BYTES_COMPARATOR = new ByteArrayComparator();
```

From ruby, how can I access the above field ?
I tried

```
Bytes:BYTES_COMPARATOR
Bytes.BYTES_COMPARATOR
```

Neither of the above worked.

Hint is appreciated

Comment: For colon, I got "NameError: uninitialized constant". For dot, I got NoMethodError

Comment: Did you try a double colon?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
Bytes::BYTES_COMPARATOR
```

Assuming you imported `Bytes`